# How can I make my requests in integration tests work?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, integration-testing, dotnet-httpclient

I'm learning to create integration tests. I configured Web Application Factory to use InMemoryDB, but it seems that my requests don't work.
It's my Custom Web Application Factory:

```
public class APIWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ProjectsDbContext>));

            if(descriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(descriptor);
            }
            services.AddDbContext<ProjectsDbContext>(options =>
            {
                var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(id);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And here's my test:

```
public WebAPIIntegrationTests(APIWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProjectsDbContext>();
    var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(id);
    var options = builder.Options;
    ProjectsDbContext context = new ProjectsDbContext(options);
    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    _userService = new UserService(new UsersRepository(context));
    _taskService = new TaskService(new TasksRepository(context));
    _projectService = new ProjectService(new ProjectsRepository(context));
    _teamService = new TeamService(new TeamsRepository(context));

    _client = factory.CreateClient();
}

[Fact]
public async void CreatingProject()
{
    var project = new Project()
    {
        Name = "Expedita amet quas id a.",
        Description = "Ea ab omnis saepe rem vel et.\nIllo quaerat eos accusantium reiciendis dolores quibusdam ratione.",
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        Deadline = DateTime.Now,
        AuthorId = 29,
        TeamId = 8
    };

    var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(project);
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj));

    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var post = await _client.PostAsync("api/projects", content);
    var get = await _client.GetAsync("api/projects/101");
    
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, get.StatusCode);
    get.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

While debugging I can see that in-memory database is working, but all requests return "Not Found".

**EDIT:**

My controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase 
{
    private readonly ProjectService _projectService;
    private readonly Service _service;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public ProjectsController(ProjectService projectService, Service service, IMapper mapper) 
    {
        _service = service;
        _projectService = projectService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<ProjectDto>> GetAllProjects()
    {
        var result = _projectService.GetAllProjects();
        return _mapper.Map<List<ProjectDto>>(result);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<ProjectDto> GetProject(int id)
    {
        var result = _projectService.GetProject(id);
        return _mapper.Map<ProjectDto>(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<ProjectDto> PostProject(ProjectDto project)
    {
        var result = _mapper.Map<Project>(project);
        _projectService.PostProject(result);
        return project;
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public NoContentResult DeleteProject(int id)
    {
        _projectService.DeleteProject(id);
        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<ProjectDto> UpdateProject(ProjectDto project)
    {
        var result = _mapper.Map<Project>(project);
        _projectService.UpdateProject(result);
        return project;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what your controller (actions) look like? It's kind of hard to say why you may be getting a NotFound without looking at the actual endpoint

Comment: @MarkDavies added controller code

Comment: I think you are overriding your own startup file.  Can you show how your WebApplicationFactory is instantiated?

Comment: @NickAcosta yes, and I thought that overriding is the sense of factory [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-webapplicationfactory). I think it's instantiating on creating HttpClient: `public WebAPIIntegrationTests(APIWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
{
    _client = factory.CreateClient();
}
`

Comment: I know if you call factory.CreateClient(); before your ConfigureServices runs, you will get a 404 when you try to make a request.  I don't see ConfigureServices being called anywhere on your application factory but I don't think you've posted everything.

Comment: @NickAcosta it's in the first code block. `builder.ConfigureServices`
But I'm just learning and maybe I'm missing something. How it should be called and where?

Comment: Here is an example test.  Notice lines 6-11. https://pastebin.com/v3w744hX